# Простой дискорд бот на пайтон

Tags: python, discord.py

Я хотел бы сделать бота для дискорда, который бы при любом сообщении проверял его на непристойные слова, а также, при вводе команды /random, выдавал случайное значение от 1 до 100. Как можно это реализовать на библио? Вот мой код:

```
words=[] #здесь слова, которые будет удалять бот
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands
settings = {
    'token': 'токен',
    'bot': 'Censor Bot',
    'id': 1025,
    'prefix': '/'
}
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author != bot.user:
        g=ctx.content
        g=g.lower()
        g = g.split()
        for i in range(len(g)):
            if g[i] in words:
                await ctx.delete()
                break
@bot.command()
async def rand(ctx, *arg):
    await ctx.reply(random.randint(0, 100))
bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Функция on_message захватывает сообщение, а не контекст, поэтому будет корректнее писать `on_message(message)`. Хоть здесь это и никак не влияет, но читаемость кода улучшает)
2. Чтобы команда `/rand` была воспринята ботом, нужно чтобы бот после проверки сообщения на запрещённые слова переходил к проверке функций. Поэтому в конце on_message напишите `await bot.process_commands(message)`

Comment: Спасибо, а если я захочу добавить еще одну команду, то просто нужно добавить после " async def rand(mes, *arg): " еще одну асинхронную функцию?

Comment: Ну да, просто также пишите декоратор `@bot.command()`, а затем асинхронную функцию